# ManifestPlaceholders for Activity class

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, manifest

I tried following:

*gradle.buid*

```
android {
     defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ launchActivityName:".ui.activities.MainActivity"]
    }
}
```

*Manifest*

```
 <activity
        android:name="${launchActivityName}"
        ...>
 </activity>
```

It seems like that I can't use `manifestPlaceholders` for the activity class. Is there another solution for my problem?

I want to decide based on a build type or flavour, which activity is the main activity...

Answer (score 0):

i think but not an optimized solution is to create a `buildConfigField` vars in you flavors,
`buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOR', '"prod"'`
`buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOR', '"beta"'`
...

create a transparent launch Activity 
in this Activity you test `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` value to decide which Activity you want to start

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use manifestPlaceholders for activity name, but try using only class name, without the package.
In my case this worked:

```
productFlavors {
        someFlavor {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ launchActivityName:"MainActivity"]
        }

    }
```